# how to remove single quotes from the output of inner query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to remove single quotes from the output of inner query as:

```
select *from demo where codes in (select codes from demo_temp);
```

Datatypes of bith columns are varchar2

output of `select codes from demo_temp` is '201,601'

I want the output to be as

```
select *from demo where codes in (201,601);---15rows
```

I have tried below but its not working:

```
select *from demo where codes in replace((select codes from demo_temp),'''','');--0rows

select *from demo where codes in (select replace(codes,'''','') from demo_temp);--0rows
```

Comment: Does your inner table have one row with '201,601'? Or multiple rows with comma-separated lists? Or just one row per number like '201' and '601'? Comma-separated list strings don't belong in a database.

Comment: I think it does not explain very well whether he was to convert the comma separated values to rows, or just remove the single quotes, or both

Comment: one row only with 201,601

Comment: i need just to remove single quotes from the inner query output

Answer (score 2):

One option is to split `codes` into rows (in a subquery):

```
SELECT *
  FROM demo
 WHERE codes IN (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (TRIM (BOTH '''' FROM codes),
                                           '[^,]+',
                                           1,
                                           LEVEL)
                       FROM demo_temp
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (codes, ',') + 1);
```

---

Will it work? I guess so, if `demo.codes` contains values such as `201` and `601`.

For example: `demo_temp.codes = '201,601'`. Split into rows, query returns `201` and `601` (with no single quotes):

```
SQL> WITH demo_temp AS (SELECT q'['201,601']' codes FROM DUAL)
  2      SELECT codes,
  3             REGEXP_SUBSTR (TRIM (BOTH '''' FROM codes),
  4                            '[^,]+',
  5                            1,
  6                            LEVEL)
  7        FROM demo_temp
  8  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (codes, ',') + 1
  9  /

CODES     REGEXP_SU
--------- ---------
'201,601' 201
'201,601' 601

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there any way we can get the output as 201,601 in the same row?

Comment: What does that mean? Which "same row"? If you're talking about what you'd want to get (and posted code `... where codes in (201,601)`) then forget about it. It just won't work that way. Correct way is to do what I suggested.

Comment: i have also tried this:  

select regexp_substr(codes,'\w+',1,1) codesfrom demo_temp;  
 
it is returning 201 only can u suggest on this as well

Comment: Certainly. It looks as if you don't know REGEXP_SUBSTR syntax so you're "lucky guessing". I posted code that works, so I suggest you use it.

Answer (score 0):

As the poster of the question requires dynamic comparison, let's do it with a simple test. The idea is to show the original column without quotes and the values in the join that matches any of the values in the comma string

```
SQL> create table t ( id number generated always as identity start with 1 increment by 1 , codes number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t ( codes ) values ( 201 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t ( codes ) values ( 601 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t ( codes ) values ( 309 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t ( codes ) values ( 501 )  ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from t ;

        ID      CODES
---------- ----------
         1        201
         2        601
         3        309
         4        501

SQL> create table x ( codes varchar2(20) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into x values ( q'('201,601')' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into x values ( q'('309,501')') ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from x ;

CODES
--------------------
'201,601'
'309,501'

SQL> with z ( lvl , codes )
    as
    ( select level lvl, regexp_substr ( codes, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) as codes
  from ( select replace(codes,'''','') as codes from x )
  connect by level <= regexp_count (codes, ',') + 1
  )
  select t.id , t.codes from t
  where t.codes in ( select z.codes from z );

        ID      CODES
---------- ----------
         1        201
         2        601
         4        501
         3        309
```

**Column original in the same row without quotes**

```
SQL> with z ( lvl , codes )
as
( select level lvl, regexp_substr ( codes, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) as codes
  from ( select replace(codes,'''','') as codes from x )
  connect by level <= regexp_count (codes, ',') + 1
)
select t.id , t.codes , replace(x.codes,'''','') as org_val 
from t cross join x 
where t.codes in ( select z.codes from z )
and
( t.codes like '%' || regexp_substr(replace(x.codes,'''',''),'[^,]+',1,1) || '%' 
  or 
  t.codes like '%' || regexp_substr(replace(x.codes,'''',''),'[^,]+',1,2) || '%'
);


       ID      CODES ORG_VAL
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1        201 201,601
         2        601 201,601
         4        501 309,501
         3        309 309,501
```

Comment: I will consider first solution but you have hardcoded the values in where clause as where replace(codes,'''','') = '201,601' , I need some dynamic generic solution

Comment: @MuditB , you did not say anything about dynamic in your original question. let me show you that in the same answer.

Comment: you have on my answer a solution that works for any data you might have in both tables

Comment: Is there any way we can get the output as 201,601 in the same row?

Comment: i have also tried this:  

select regexp_substr(codes,'\w+',1,1) codesfrom demo_temp;  
 
it is returning 201 only can u suggest on this as well

Comment: @MuditB check my updated answer, with the column you want to. If it is what you want, I would appreciate you accept and upvote the answer